# How to serialize canonical/normalized JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

The order of keys in JSON is not relevant, so PHP's `json_encode` uses the internal order of keys when serializing JSON format. I'd like to make sure that equivalent JSON is always serialized the same form. For instance `$a` and `$b` in the following example

```
$a = ["foo" => 1, "bar" => 2, "doz" => 3];
$b = ["doz" => 3, "bar" => 2, "foo" => 1];
print json_encode($a)."\n";
print json_encode($b)."\n";
```

result in different serializations

```
{"foo":1,"bar":2,"doz":3}
{"doz":3,"bar":2,"foo":1}
```

but they are equivalent.

Comment: `ksort` before encoding...!?

Comment: @deceze yes but recursively.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort the array in some way, I recommend sorting by key (foo, bar, doz).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

The order will always be the same when using the same keys.

I haven't tested this, but it should work for your code.

```
$a = ["foo" => 1, "bar" => 2, "doz" => 3];
$b = ["doz" => 3, "bar" => 2, "foo" => 1];
ksort($a);
ksort($b);
print json_encode($a)."\n";
print json_encode($b)."\n";
```

This will print:

> {"bar":2,"doz":3,"foo":1}
>
> {"bar":2,"doz":3,"foo":1}

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to ksort. Your solution does not work for recursive arrays but it's a good start.